# What is the command for inline help in tmux?

Tags: tmux

In `vim`, we have `:help`. In `R`, we have `?topic`.

I seem to remember there is an option inside `tmux` to get help on `tmux` commands, but I cannot remember it and could not find it online.

Update: I tried a bunch of things and finally found `list-commands`, but I am not sure if more detail can be obtained inline, as opposed to using the `man` page.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried `Ctrl+b` then `?` ? Also if you hit Ctrl+b, then type `:list-commands`. You should see something useful.

Comment: I think I was only trying commands that started with `:`. `C-b,?` was the command that I was looking for.